# Punishments for certain ervahs

Tags: capital-punishment

This table below is from a chumash from the parsha Acharei.

1. It is shown that a union with a sister is punished by lashes, if it was intentional plus witnessed plus a warning. I think the punishment should be burning too.
2. It also says that a union with a non-Jewish woman, if it was intentional without witnesses is excision. I don't think that it is excision but rather something else.  I say this because she is not a 100% ervah like ur mom or aunt or sis etc.

Can someone comfirm that the table is indeed correct?

[image]

Comment: Hi Mars, which chumash?

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii Kehot Chumash

https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2192387/jewish/Kehot-Chumash.htm

Comment: See the last mishna in makkot כל חייבי כרתות שלקו, נפטרו מידי כרתן

Comment: @שלום You can't derive a punishment from outside the 5 books. That won't stand in a Jewish court. Any and all administrative procedures/ punishments/ charges should come from the 5 books.

Comment: @שלום Are you saying that every Jewish man who is married to a non-Jewish woman right now, is liable for excision?

Comment: @שלום    Since when did not knowing better, give anyone a free pass?

Comment: No burning for a sister